# Are you allowed to use different sci fi terms for an official published project?

Tags: copyright, trademark

’m working on a project for a sci-fi franchise and I was wondering if I am allowed to use concepts I thought up of that also appear in a Google Search after the fact. So I have a term I want to use but someone has used it online. Is it legal to use it since I thought of it on my own?

Comment: It's not clear whether you're talking about using "terms" or "concepts," and the difference may be material. I'd recommend adding more detail to your question to elicit higher-quality answers.

Comment: Cross-posted [from worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/234776/are-you-allowed-to-use-different-sci-fi-terms-for-an-official-project). We recommend that you don't do that without first deleting the original as if it gets left it's just clutter for the network.

Answer (score 2):

Names might be protected by trademark law. For example, Lucas Films and now by extension Disney has [a trademark on the word "Droid"](https://alter.com/trademarks/droid-75878790) , so if your work contains robots, you better call them something else. If your robots happen to be large and well-armed, then you might think about calling them "Mechs", but that might also get you into trouble, because it's [a trademark FASA enforces for their Battletech franchise](https://alter.com/trademarks/mech-73626301).

So if you consider using the name of a science fiction concept you picked up somewhere, first make sure that it's not a registered trademark.

But there are also [*unregistered* trademarks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unregistered_trademark) which can be legally enforced. The prerequisite for enforcing an unregistered trademark is that the name is "used in commerce". That means that the person who wants to enforce the trademark must sell some product or service under that name. So if someone "used the term online", make sure they don't use it commercially.

Comment: This rather badly overstates the degree of protection that a trademark can give.

Comment: I’ll give an example. I like the term “Hyperspace brain”. I googled it and stuff comes up. There is even a song or musical group called that. Am I not allowed to use the term even though we are using it for different things?